# Why do we break down unsorted lists by halves with Merge Sort?

Tags: sorting, big-o, mergesort

Suppose we have a unsorted list [7,10,18,2,9,45]. Using the merge sort, we'd break it down by halves

> [7,10,18,2,9,45]
>
> [7,10,18] [2,9,45]
>
> [7,10] [18] [2,9] [45]
>
> [7] [10] [18] [2] [9] [45]

Then work back up. However, why do we want to break it into halves like that? Why would you not just start by taking the initial unsorted list and break it immediately into the base-case of 1 element lists, then work back up by combining two of those 1-element lists at a time, like so:

> [7,10,18,2,9,45]
>
> [7] [10] [18] [2] [9] [45]

Why go through all the intermediate steps of halving the unsorted list? Would that impact the big-O?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the recursive splitting not just to break down this list into sublists, but also to control merging of the lists, as you recurse "back up" after sorting the sublists.

If you instead iteratively split off one element at a time and then merged them back in one element at a time, you would end up with an O(*n<sup>2</sup>*) algorithm instead of O(*n* log(*n*))

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I just didn't grasp the iterative vs recursive idea of this right away. Thanks a bunch, man.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a good question but you are thinking in a iterative mode. In the activation register you have to know that mergesort breaks the array in a recursive mode. I mean, you have mergesort in this way:

```
  [3,7,4,8,10,9] --> [3] [7] [4] [8] [10] [9]
```

This is done in a set of recursive mode but if you call in an iterative mode and separates all these values with a loop, you don't have a status in the functions because you have a set of values which is separated but where do you have the registers that contain the values for merging all of them? You have to take account that the registers mode save the values and after that deactivate the register and merge the values doing this:

```
[3] [7] [4] [8] [10] [9] --->  [3, 7] [4,8] [9, 10]
```

Do you notice the change? this is way you need a recursive call, because you decompose the previous state and merge again and again. 
I hope that I help you.

Comment: Yes, now I understand. I just missed the iterative versus the recursive implication. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

> Why would you not just start by taking the initial unsorted list and break it immediately into the base-case of 1 element lists, then work back up by combining two of those 1-element lists at a time?

Starting with the base case of 1 element lists (runs) is how a bottom up iterative merge sort is done. It's slightly faster since pairs of indexes are not pushed onto and popped from a stack. Most libraries use some variation of a bottom up merge sort. Wiki article includes pseudo code:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation